# GCP kms encrypt env var and passing encrypted key through cloudbuild.yaml to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

I'm trying to encrypt env vars for database in Cloud SQL in my RoR app deploying to Google App Engine. Following this doc https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials

However, I have an error when running both `gcloud builds submit` and `gcloud app deploy`. Both are error out with:

> Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED / build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1.

I then check the `gcloud builds described` shows that the app failed to deploy, however, `DATABASE_PASS` shows working/queued. I have increase the Cloud Build component in `gcloud` sdk to 1000 and testing timeout: in `cloudbuild.yaml;` both options didn't improve anything.

Before using Cloud Build my app was working but I'm erasing the need of credentials and using encrypted credentials for CI/CD pipeline. Also, would like to encrypt more than one env var in my `app.yaml`.

```
 <cloudbuild.yaml>
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app','deploy','app-beta.yaml']

- name: 'us.gcr.io/project_ID/image_name'
  #args: [ 'app', 'deploy', 'app-beta.yaml' ]
  secretEnv: [ "DATABASE_PASS" ]


secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/Project_id/locations/global/keyRings/Misc/cryptoKeys/Random
  secretEnv: 
      DATABASE_PASS:< base64 encoded encryption> 

<app.yaml> 
runtime: custom

env: flex

service: authentication

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: '/cloudsql/project_id:us-central1:sqlname'

network:
  name: default

skip_files:
  - .ruby-gemset
  - .env
  - .bundle
  - .byebug_history
  - .vscode/
  - .idea/
  - storage/
  - vendor/
  - log/
  - tmp/

#liveness_check:
#path: '/liveness-check'
#   initial_delay_sec: 300
#   check_interval_sec: 30
#   timeout_sec: 4
#   failure_threshold: 2
#   success_threshold: 2
#
# readiness_check:
#   path: '/readiness-check'
#   check_interval_sec: 5
#   timeout_sec: 4
#   failure_threshold: 2
#   success_threshold: 2
#   app_start_timeout_sec: 300

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: 'SECRET_KEY'
  RAILS_ENV: 'redacted'
  RACK_ENV: 'redacted'
  SERVICE_NAME: 'redacted'
  REDIS_HOST: '10.0.0.3'
  REDIS_PORT: 6379
  TOTP_SECRET: 'TOTP_SECRET'
  DATABASE_USER: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASS: 'DATABASE_PASS'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_HOST: '/cloudsql/project_id:us-central1:sqlname'
  RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: enabled
  RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, one was that when I used the gcloud kms encryption. I wasn't encrypting anything. So was passing in an empty value. I'll throw up my solution on a blog and hyperlink to it.

Comment: Did you write that blogpost?

Comment: So I have written the post but the site I'm using is not allowing me to post is publicly.

Comment: https://dev.to/pauld/deploy-ror-on-gae-and-codeship-ci-cd-pipeline-21k4